Power series solution to $x^2y''+y'+y=0$ around $x=0$
If an ODE of the form
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$
has $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ that are analytic at $x_0$ then we can suppose a power series solution as such:
$$y(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n(x-x_0)^n$$
If instead they have a first order pole at $x_0$ we have to suppose this other one:
$$y(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n(x-x_0)^{n+r}$$
But what about a power series solution with coefficients that have higher order poles at $x_0$ like in this particular case where there is a $2^{\text{nd}}$ order pole at $x=0$?:
$$x^2y''+y'+y=0$$
Is there any possible power series solution at $x=0$?

There is $y(x) = 0$ as a trivial soultion.

Note that in this example, $x=0$ is not a regular singular point.  The Frobenius series-solution method fails.

Right, it is an irregular singular point. The book I'm referring to says we can't use any of those methods, but doesn't mention either what to do in this situation...

Maple series solver does not handle irreqular singular point. Need to use asymptotic expansion method for this. standard power series and Frobenius series do not work.
Mathematica has such a function.
ode = x^2*y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, y[x], {x, 0, 5}]

gives
$$
c_2 e^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(\frac{59241 x^5}{40}+\frac{1911 x^4}{8}+\frac{91 x^3}{2}+\frac{21 x^2}{2}+3 x+1\right) x^2+c_1 \left(-\frac{91 x^5}{40}+\frac{7
   x^4}{8}-\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}-x+1\right)
$$
I've asked the good folks at Maplesoft to have the series ode solver support irreqular singular point few years ago but so far there does not seem to be interest in doing so and as of Maple 2024 there is no direct option to do this. You have to add and write your own Maple code to handle such cases.
reference  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html

Note that in this example, $x=0$ is not a regular singular point.  The Frobenius series-solution method fails.
Maple's series solution looks like
$$y(x) = C{x}^{2}{{\rm e}^{{x}^{-1}}}
+3\,C{x}^{3}{{\rm e}^{{x}^{-1}}}
+{\frac {21\,C{x}^{4}{{\rm e}^{{x}^{-1}}}}{2}}
+{\frac {91\,C{x}^{5}{{\rm e}^{{x}^{-1}}}}{2}}
+\dots
$$
as $x \to 0$

Thanks, fixed...

Thanks for the solution. Do you know what method did Maple use to solve this ODE? Because it kinda looks like a product of an exponential and a power series. Or at least do you know anywhere I can read about this topic (solution when ODEs have higher order poles)? At last, shouldn't there be two unknown constants or is this only one of the solutions?

"What method" ??  Well, I cheated.  Maple solved the DE in terms of Bessel functions (of complex order), then I expanded that solution using the MultiSeries[series] command.  Looking at the answer suggests the following method.  Write $u = y/\exp(1/x)$, convert the original to a DE for $u$.
